# PHPSpreadsheet, Drawing - move and size with cells

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I try to set the setting "Move and size with cells" for my images in PHPSpreadsheet, but cant find any information anywhere. Now my question is, if that feature is implemented yet, and if it is, how its called.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is too late for "help YOU" but this will be useful for another people

I had the same problem and found 2 "things"

1. Nothing
2. Google is a bunch of millons links/sublinks to 50 top-web. Google is the old AOL of 1998

But, I didn't give up and I could "fix" it. Actually, in the folder of PHPSpreadsheet you will see the next next path folder;

- /PhpOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx

There're a file called: **Drawing.php**, in this file you will find a function called: ***writeDrawing***

there you will find the following code;
[Line: 152]

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('xdr:oneCellAnchor');
```

It must be replace with:

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('xdr:twoCellAnchor');
```

After, 2 o 3 lines, under those code you will find this code;
[Line:166 to 169]

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('xdr:ext');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('cx', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Drawing::pixelsToEMU($pDrawing->getWidth()));
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('cy', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Drawing::pixelsToEMU($pDrawing->getHeight()));
    $objWriter->endElement();
```

Add comment marks like "//" or "/* code */" and comment it for avoid these code lines. And now, add the following code;

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('xdr:to');
    $objWriter->writeElement('xdr:col', $aCoordinates[0] - 1);
    $objWriter->writeElement('xdr:colOff', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Drawing::pixelsToEMU($pDrawing->getWidth()));
    $objWriter->writeElement('xdr:row', $aCoordinates[1]);
    $objWriter->writeElement('xdr:rowOff', "0");
    $objWriter->endElement();
```

In  the following code, should be fix
[Line:178 to 182]

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('xdr:cNvPr');

    $objWriter->writeAttribute('id', $pRelationId);
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('name', $pDrawing->getName());
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('descr', $pDrawing->getDescription());
    $objWriter->endElement();
```

the fixed code (don't add "***$objWriter->endElement()***");

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('xdr:cNvPr');

    $objWriter->writeAttribute('name', $pDrawing->getName() . $pRelationId);
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('descr', $pDrawing->getDescription());
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('id', $pRelationId+1);
```

At Now, in the [Line: 183] ***INSERT*** this code;

```php
    $objWriter->startElement('a:extLst');
    $objWriter->startElement('a:ext');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('uri', "{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}");
    $objWriter->endElement(); // this close a:ext
    $objWriter->endElement(); // this close a:extLst
    $objWriter->endElement(); // thise xdr:cNvPr [this will replace the $objWriter->endElement(); of Line 182. It was lost in the previous step
```

Now, a code like this;

```php
   require "../../PhpOffice/vendor/autoload.php";

   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

   $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

   $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
...
   $imgfile = base64_decode($img_from_query_sql);
   $fname = "../tmp/".rand(). ".xlsx";

   file_put_contents($fname, $imgfile);
   $drawing = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing(); 

   $Cell = $Letter[$j] . $row;

   $drawing->setPath($fname);

   $drawing->setCoordinates($Cell );

   $drawing->setResizeProportional(false);

   $drawing->setWidth(300);

   $drawing->setHeight(300);

   $drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);

   $sheet->setTitle("TitleOfSheet");

   $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

   $writer->save("php://output");

...
```

Execute and download your excel with images. Check your images: right click->"Size and properties..."
Will appear a right-panel of "Image format". In sub-menu "properties" should be a 3 "radio option" (circle with black point)

1. Move and size with cells
2. Move but don't size with cells
3. Don't move or size with cells

Phpspreadsheet orignally, makes pictures with option 2-> ***Move but don't size with cells*** but, we changed the code of Drawing.php and now all images are created with option 1->***Move and size with cells***

At now, if we have a excel file with a list of "things" and 1 image per row, we can apply filters and if some rows doesn't have any image the following image-row will not overlapping over the visible row (matching results).
Each picture filtered will be hidden with is parent row, and each picture matching with filter will be 'stick' to his parent row as always should have been

## UPDATE: 28-07-22 - SpreadSheet 1.23

In *vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Drawing.php* still exist a function called **writeDrawing** in line 184;

This functions has changed a bit since the last version I used. Now, writeDrawing have many improves and doesn't require edit any codeline;
Currenly, "BaseDrawing" is a data type that have a new method called;
**setCoordinates2** (two) instead of **setCoordinates** (withtout "2" at end)

You can use setCoordinates2 in your main_custom_file_excel_creator.php like;

```
   $Cell = "A2";
   $drawing->setCoordinates2($Cell); //instead of setCoordinates
```

The updated function (**writeDrawing**) from line 184 to 340, will use **$drawing**. This **$drawing** variable is type **BaseDrawing** so, in line 187 it will check if is set or not and will store a boolean in **$isTwoCellAnchor**

It will help us for some setting like @Wind Cloud was looking. Can be solved doing a simple;

```
   $drawing->setEditAs("absolute");
```

The new version 1.23 (2022-jul-28) have better class Drawing;
Now you can do it without any edit. You only need set the correct methods;
for *Move but don't size with cells*

```
   require "../../PhpOffice/vendor/autoload.php";

   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

   $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

   $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
...
   $imgfile = base64_decode($img_from_query_sql);
   $fname = "../tmp/somefile123.xlsx";

   file_put_contents($fname, $imgfile);
   $drawing = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing(); 

   $Cell = "A2";

   $drawing->setPath($fname);
   $drawing->setCoordinates2($Cell ); //USE THE NEW METHOD SETTER
   $drawing->setResizeProportional(false);
   $drawing->setWidth(300);
   $drawing->setHeight(300);
   $drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
   $sheet->setTitle("TitleOfSheet");
   $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
   $writer->save("php://output");
```

A user called Wind Cloud asked;

> I want to set "Don't move or size with cells" instead. Do you know
> how? – Wind Cloud

In the new version ^1.23 will be very easy;

```
   require "../../PhpOffice/vendor/autoload.php";

   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
   use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

   $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

   $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
...
   $imgfile = base64_decode($img_from_query_sql);
   $fname = "../tmp/somefile123.xlsx";

   file_put_contents($fname, $imgfile);
   $drawing = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing(); 

   $Cell = "A2";

   $drawing->setPath($fname);
   $drawing->setCoordinates**2**($Cell);
   $drawing->setEditAs("absolute"); //HERE IS YOUR KEY
   $drawing->setResizeProportional(false);
   $drawing->setWidth(300);
   $drawing->setHeight(300);
   $drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
   $sheet->setTitle("TitleOfSheet");
   $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
   $writer->save("php://output");
```

Comment: do you have an up to date answer for this. I tried it in xlxs folder and it id not work.

Comment: I'll try see this night to see if something has changed. If I got some changes i'll update it in few hours after see it

pd: now is 15:13 / 03:15 P.M. for me. I'll check it arround ~ 22:00 / 10:00 P.M.

Comment: I want to set "Don't move or size with cells" instead. Do you know how? @MaximilianoBertiaux

Comment: @WindCloud Hi. If you want to set "Don't move or size with cells" (3rd option) you should edit this line;

$objWriter->startElement('xdr:oneCellAnchor');

$objWriter->startElement('xdr:twoCellAnchor editAs="absolute"');

in my original post, I set
$objWriter->startElement('xdr:twoCellAnchor"');  
Keep this modify but add plus **editAs="absolute"** as extra param

Comment: Hi again. @WindCloud. I gave you an answer here but I've update this post too. You should check my update. Will be useful for what you ask

Comment: @MaximilianoBertiaux Hi, Thank you so much for your support, But I think with option **setEditAs("absolute")** we can not use setWidth and setHeight anymore, and I think we also need to set this property **setCoordinates** also. Because **twoCellAnchor** need it to draw **from** value and  setCoordinates2 for **to** value. If we don't set setCoordinates it will alway draw from **A** column.